# mysql deleting duplicates from table

Tags: mysql

I can find the duplicates by :

```
select id,date,count(*) as rep,comment
     from New_opinion group by comment,
     Date,company_id having rep>1;
```

I believe this gives me one record in the group of duplicates that are matched by the same comment, Date and company_id which is close but only shows one of the matching duplicates.

I'd like to select all but one of the duplicates and delete them. 
id is a primary key
I've worked on this for hours, and keep getting errors about operands need 1 columns, or deleting a non key, etc. Please help, the other delete answers don't seem to be working.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
DELETE FROM New_opinion n WHERE n.comment,n.Date,n.company_id 
IN( 
    SELECT temp.comment,temp.Date,temp.company_id FROM 
    (SELECT comment,Date,company_id, id,date,count(*) AS rep,comment
     FROM New_opinion 
     GROUP BY comment,Date,company_id 
     HAVING rep>1 ) temp);
```

I hope this will work..

Answer (score 0):

Your comment group has multiple ids, which is why you can't use them for a DELETE.

Try a `GROUP_CONCAT(id)` in the field list to see the list of id numbers.

Not enough for the group contents to be similar - its only a useful group in terms of those fields if every field is identical which given the presence of a primary key it won't be.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to keep the row with lowest id

```
DELETE r1 FROM tableName r1, tableName r2 WHERE r1.id > r2.id AND r1.x = r2.x
```

To keep the row with highest id just change

```
WHERE r1.id < r2.id
```

Answer (score 0):

say you have three duplicates for company SMITH & SON, does it matter which of those rows is kept? if it does (say the newest one per company by date) then you might want to select those to a new table, then truncate the old table and then copy the values from the new table back to the old table and then add a unique index across those columns. if it doesn't matter which are kept but just one of each then you can add the index immediately, telling it to ignore the table, and that will immediately drop the duplicates leaving one random row for each company where duplicates happen. The latter like this:

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE yourtablename ADD UNIQUE companyid, date, comment
```

if you need the latest per date in case of duplicates for each company, see the tutorial in the manual under GROUPWISE MAXIMUM